# Data Readiness Check

Tags: oracle, compare, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, replication

Let's say there is a job A which executes a Python to connect to Oracle, fetch the data from Table A and load the data into Snowflake once a day. Application A dependent on Table A in Snowflake can just depend on the success of job A for further processing, this is easy.

But if the data movement is via Replication (Change Data Capture from Oracle moves to s3 using Golden Gate, pipes pushes into stage, stream to target using Task every few mins) - what is the best way to let Application A know that the data is ready? How to check if the data is ready? is there something available in Oracle, like a table level marker that can be moved over to Snowflake? Table's in Oracle cannot be modified to add anything new, marker rows also cannot be added - these are impractical. But something that Oracle provides implicitly, which can be moved over to Snowflake or some SCN like number at the table level that can be compared every few minutes could be a solution, eager to know any approaches.

Comment: Have you looked into streams? Both Oracle and Snowflake support them. Oracle Streams: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17069/strms_over.htm. Snowflake streams: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams.html

Comment: @GregPavlik "Oracle Database 18c is the terminal release for support of the Oracle Streams feature. Oracle Streams will be desupported from Oracle Database 19 onwards."

Comment: @OldProgrammer thank you for the information on that.